# In the Christmas Pageant scene, what did Buzz do to Kevin?

Tags: plot-explanation, home-alone, home-alone-2-lost-in-new-york

**I am *completely blind,*** so I cannot see what is happening. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a version that contained audio descriptions, and searching various sites such as Wikipedia, WikiFandom, or IMDB yielded no favourable results..
For reference, here's the scene on YouTube.

From what I could hear, people started laughing during Kevin's solo, and then a while later, some sources told me that a Christmas tree knocked over the pianist. But I don't know what happened in between that.

Comment: What assistive technology are you using that helps locate the right scene in youtube?  Serious question.

Comment: I used a screen reader called NVDA, and I searched for Christmas Pageant on Google.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The singers have electric lights that are shaped to look like candles. Buzz, like the other singers, starts with one, but takes another from the singer next to him and holds them up to Kevin's ears. The lights are bright enough and close enough to Kevin's ears to shine through  them.

Buzz then moves the lights in a manner that imitates the use of drumsticks on a drum, with Kevin's head being where the drum would be, then resumes putting them behind Kevin's ears. Kevin turns around and pushes Buzz, which knocks him over. As he falls, his arms flail, hitting the people next to him, causing them to fall over and hit the people next to them, and so on. This chain reaction causes everyone (except, for some reason, Kevin), to fall over. They knock over a large piece of scenery made to look like a Christmas tree, which then hits the pianist.

I'm not sure how much that is referring to things you'd be familiar with; if you're blind from birth, you haven't had much use for candles, or the electric lights made to imitate them, and you wouldn't be familiar with the phenomenon of bright lights being visible through thin parts of one's body.

Comment: This is an excellent answer - its clear you took OP's comment into account, and provided a plain text answer suitable for a screen-reader.

Comment: In particular on that last paragraph, it may help to try to explain something of the distinction between something being transparent (if I was holding a candle close behind a beer bottle you would be able to see a candle through the bottle) and something being translucent (if I was holding a candle behind a thin sheet of paper you would perceive a light behind it, but not necessarily its detailed shape). It's a bit like the distinction between feeling the shape of an object (by touching it) that you noticed because it was warm versus just feeling the warmth from near the object.

Comment: Great response, very clear. If anything, right after _"[...] then resumes putting them behind Kevin's ears."_, I would add something along the lines of "Unbeknownst to Kevin, who is still singing and facing the audience".

Answer (score 20):

### Unfortunately, the joke is completely visual.

Buzz is holding his electric candle lights behind Kevin's ears so that it emphasises how large they are by making them see-through.

[image: Screenshot of Buzz holding candle lights behind Kevin's ears]

[image: Close shot of see-through ears]

He then pretends to play drums on Kevin's head using the lights.

[image: Gif of Buzz pretending to play drums on Kevin's head]

Comment: I like how you include screenshots for a blind person asking to describe the scene.

Comment: Hence the descriptions of the images which accompany them and the title of the images themselves. The images are for the *sighted* who also read the questions and answers